# Trouble with unset()

Tags: php, arrays, unset

### Dumbed Down for Illustration Purposes

- PHP 5.27 (Required).
- Error Reporting is on.

I'm trying to use an array `$unset` to unset an associative array `$list` value if one of its properties `$list['id']`  is present in the array `$unset`.

However, I'm having so trouble understanding the outcome here:

```
<?php
$list = array(
  array(
    'id' => 'foo'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 'bar'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 'baz'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 'quix'
  )
);

$unset = array(
  'foo',
);

for ($i=0; $i < count($list); $i++) { 
  echo "Itteration: {$i}" . '<br />';
  echo "Contest ID: {$list[$i]['id']}" . '<br />';
  echo 'Not in Array: ', (!in_array($list[$i]['id'], $unset)) ? 'True' : 'False';

  unset($list[$i]); // Trouble Section
  echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

Output:

```
Itteration: 0
Contest ID: foo
Not in Array: False

Itteration: 1
Contest ID: bar
Not in Array: True
```

Regardless of the number of values in `$unset` I only successfully run 2 iterations.

When I remove `unset($list[$i]);` we successfully iterate through `$list`:

```
Itteration: 0
Contest ID: foo
Not in Array: False

Itteration: 1
Contest ID: bar
Not in Array: True

Itteration: 2
Contest ID: baz
Not in Array: True

Itteration: 3
Contest ID: quix
Not in Array: True
```

I can't find an explanation [in the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) as to why this would happen. The only caveat that the docs talk about is using `unset` in a function on globals. I even tried `unset($GLOBALS['list'][$i])` just for fun, with no change in result.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @niet's answer:

These two are completely different loops:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
```

and

```
$cnt = count($list);
for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
```

In the first loop, `count()` is evaluated on every loop iteration, so as you delete items from the list, `count($list)` will also decrease.

In the second loop, you count the list ONCE, cache that value, and then check the cached value each time. The second loop would iterate over all items in the `list` array, because you're using fixed goalposts. The first loop moves the goalposts closer together each time.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, was assigning count to a variable and using that. I don't know why that passed by me.

Comment: You'd have been fine if you weren't changing the array within the loop. But since you were, your loop conditions were also changing.

Comment: As an explanation for choosing this as an answer, it gives an explanation as to **why** and a resolution in the **current context**.

Answer (score 7):

This is because `count($list)` keeps getting smaller when you delete items.

Try `foreach($list as $i=>$item) {`

Comment: in other words: `for(... count())` has the count() evaluated on EVERY iteration of the loop, so it reflects the current "live" count of the array, not the count that was in the array before the loop started.

Comment: What a silly misstep, thank you. I ended up assigning a variable to count and using that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you calculate number of array items each time. It has 2 drawbacks: if you unset items as in this case your loop doesn't work as expected, and in addition you loose performance (in each iteration number of array have to be calculated once again).

The best solution for your loop is changing:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
```

into

```
for ($i=0, $c = count($list); $i <$c; ++$i) {
```

and you can in fact use this method almost each time you use for loop.